# call a function within a function in angularjs controller

Tags: php, function, angularjs

i wish to call a function inside another function in angularjs. for eg. i have a function to fetch records from database and now i need to fetch from database every time any function gets called. 
controller:-

```
function SearchCtrl($scope, $http, $element) {

        // i wish to put this into a function and call it in every function like add,search,etc.
        $http.get('php/products.php').success(function(data){
            $scope.products = data;
        });

        $scope.search = function() {
            var elem = angular.element($element);
            var dt = $(elem).serialize();
            dt = dt+"&action=index";
            //alert(dt);
            console.log($(elem).serialize());
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'php/products.php',
                data: dt,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).success(function(data, status) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.products = data; // Show result from server in our <pre></pre> element
            }).error(function(data, status) {
                $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
                $scope.status = status;
            });
        };

        //~ add
        $scope.add = function() {
            var elem = angular.element($element);
            var dt = $(elem).serialize();
            dt = dt+"&action=add";
            //alert(dt);
            console.log($(elem).serialize());
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'php/products.php',
                data: dt,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).success(function(data, status) {
                $scope.search(); //i wish to call the function like this instead of replicating the code as below each time
                //~ $http.get('php/products.php').success(function(data){
                //~ $scope.products = data;
            }); // Show result from server in our <pre></pre> element
            }).error(function(data, status) {
                $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
                $scope.status = status;
            });
        };
```

how do i do this?

Comment: because i am using php as my model and i thought if anyone has worked with php as model and faced the same issue then it would be of some help

Answer (score 6):

If I'm reading your question properly you can put this code:

```
// i wish to put this into a function and call it in every function like add,search,etc.
$http.get('php/products.php').success(function (data) {
    $scope.products = data;
});
```

into a function like this in your controller:

```
var getProducts = function () {
    $http.get('php/products.php').success(function (data) {
        $scope.products = data;
    });
};
```

and call it wherever you want in that same controller:

`getProducts();`